# Verify if model is ok for 3D Printing?

Tags: 3d-printing

I have made a model for 3d printing, I knowthere are some checks I need to do in order to have a good print, but I cant find a place where to see all the bullet points to check.

Is there a page or document where i can see all the things i should have in mind when sending a model to print?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the user prefs > add-ons > mesh > 3D Print Toolbox __ options are in the side panel in Object or Edit mode.